# Listview will not populate

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

Alright I'm stuck on populating a ListView in Android.  This must be a tiring question for you guys but I can't find the problem.  Basically it will produce placements in the ListView to hold texts, but it wont produce text.  I checked my database class and it seems to be storing the data correctly, and I checked the syntax, but I cant find the problem.

Main activity that holds the list view

```
public class MainScreen extends ListActivity {

    private TextView roommateId;
    dbHelper db = new dbHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        Log.i("Created", "main created");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> roommates = db.getAllRoommates();

        if(roommates.size()!=0){
            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    roommateId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roommateId);
                    String roommateIdValue = roommateId.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), RoommateView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("roommateId", roommateIdValue);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainScreen.this, roommates, R.layout.contact_entry,
                    new String[] {"roommateId", "firstName", "lastName"},
                    new int[]{R.id.roommateId, R.id.lastName, R.id.firstName});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Database code that returns the array list

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllRoommates(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase data = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = data.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                HashMap<String,String> roommateMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                roommateMap.put(ID, cursor.getString(0));
                Log.d("Roommate ID", cursor.getString(0));
                roommateMap.put(FIRST_NAME, cursor.getString(1));
                Log.d("First Name", cursor.getString(1));
                roommateMap.put(LAST_NAME, cursor.getString(2));

                list.add(roommateMap);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

contact entry xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/last_name"
            android:id="@+id/lastName"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/first_name"
            android:id="@+id/firstName"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/id"
            android:id="@+id/roommateId"/>
</TableRow>
```

Main screen xml

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactsTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="#444444"
                android:onClick="showAddRoommate"
                android:text="@string/add_roommate"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: No errors in the logcat?

Comment: Nothing that I could see specifically about my program, just some things talking about the email app not working.  But I'm just a novice and still learning so I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: Do you have a `catch(Exception)` or similar somewhere in your code? If so what's the body of the catch?

Comment: No catches, I'm guessing I should put one somewhere?  I don't seem to be having any problem running it, no crashing when I try to add someone, the db is recording them as I can see when I did a log.d and printed out the results.  The only time the app fails is when I try to click on a listview item, but thats not the problem I'm focusing on.  As for the catch(exception) any advice where I should put it?

Comment: Not related but instead of `if(cursor.moveToFirst()) do{}while` you can simply do `while(cursor.moveToNext())`. Cursor is before first when returned.

Comment: Where are you assigning the DB data to the list adapter? I don't see this code. Also are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after modifying the list adapter?

Comment: The roommates = db.getAllRoommates(); which returns arrayList contains the hashmap for the data.  Also no, I'm trying to look it up right now to see if I need it and how to use it.  But from what's happening is that it's producing spots for text to appear, it's just that they're empty rectangles with no text.  If I add another contact, it just adds another empty rectangle.

Comment: That's a List of Maps. I don't think that will work. That list should have the exact element to print (e.g. String).

Comment: Yeah but the simpleAdapter is supposed to take a list of maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I found the problem, it was that the String array in the simple adapter wasn't corresponding to the hash map key values, so when it was looking for key values that were not in the Hash Map. Change that and it populated.  Putting the answer down incase anyone in the future sees this post.